# question about 2 dimension array and pointer (C language)

Tags: c

I cannot understand about my code's result.

```
int td[][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
printf("%p\n", td[0]);
printf("%p\n", &td[0]);
printf("%p\n", &td[0][0]);
```

I wonder why the result of "printf("%p\n", &td[0]);" is same as other printf results.

Shouldn't there be a different result?

Comment: All of these are (or decay to) a pointer to the first element in the array.

Comment: @paddy: There is no “decay” in the third one.

Comment: Why would they not be the same? Wouldn't _that_ have been super strange?

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't there be a different result?

No.

---

All 3 become addresses as passed into a `...` function.

Passing array `td[0]` converts to `&td[0][0]` when passed as a `...` argument - so those 2 are always print the same.

`td[0]`, `&td[0]`, `&td[0][0]` are all *equivalent* addresses of different types.  They point to the same place in memory.  Some *may* have *different* encodings (yet most memory models cause them to have the same encoding), yet all 3 are *equivalent*, even if the printout differs.

---

Technically, each should be cast to `void *` before being passed as an argument to match a `"%p"`.

Comment: I think I got the concept wrong. Thank you.